# Ruby: access array of hashes grouped by two attributes for "take_while" iteration

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this array of hashes:

```
tasks = [{:id=>19, :position_id=>3, :value=>2.55, :from=>2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300},
        {:id=>10, :position_id=>3, :value=>0.16, :from=>2017-09-04 06:00:00 +0300}]
```

and this other one:

```
 inventory = 
 {[3, 2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300]=>
  [{:id=>19, :position_id=>3, :value=>2.55, :day_part=>2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300},
   {:id=>18, :position_id=>3, :value=>2.55, :day_part=>2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300}],
  [3, 2017-09-04 06:00:00 +0300]=>
  [{:id=>11, :position_id=>3, :value=>0.57, :day_part=>2017-09-04 06:00:00 +0300},
   {:id=>10, :position_id=>3, :value=>0.16, :day_part=>2017-09-04 06:00:00 +0300}]}
```

I'd like to do `take_while` for each grouped `inventory` with something like this:

```
results = tasks.map do |bt|
  inventory[bt[:position_id],bt[:from]].take_while do |inv|
#do something here
```

however this does not work as I get this error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)` and it points to line `inventory[bt[:position_id],bt[:from]].take_while do |inv|`

Expected result would be that I can do `take_while` over grouped `inventory` where grouped attributes match `position_id` and `from` from `tasks`.

How would I fix this, please? Thank you.

**Update**

These are my arrays of hashes:

```
tasks = [{id:19, position_id:3, value:2.55, from: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,0,0,'+03:00')},
         {id:10, position_id:3, value:0.16, from: DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,0,0,'+03:00')}]

inventory = 
  {[3, DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,0,0,'+03:00')]=>
   [{:id=>19, :position_id=>3, :value=>2.55, :day_part=>DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,0,0,'+03:00')},
    {:id=>18, :position_id=>3, :value=>2.55, :day_part=>DateTime.new(2017,9,4,18,0,0,'+03:00')}],
   [3, DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,0,0,'+03:00')]=>
   [{:id=>11, :position_id=>3, :value=>0.57, :day_part=>DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,0,0,'+03:00')},
    {:id=>10, :position_id=>3, :value=>0.16, :day_part=>DateTime.new(2017,9,4,6,0,0,'+03:00')}]}
```

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
results = tasks.map do |bt|
  key = bt[:position_id], bt[:from].to_s
  inventory[key].take_while do |inv|
  #do something here
```

and I get error `NoMethodError: undefined method "take_while" for nil:NilClass`

If I change to hard-coded value like this `key = [3, "2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300"]` it works as expected.

I'm confused since I'm sure my `key = bt[:position_id], bt[:from].to_s` gives me array similar to hard-coded value.

Comment: _"this does not work"_ - can you add what the expected result should be, and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: @mikej Please, see added info above.

Comment: @mudasobwa Please, see my Update above. I will need `take_while` later in my code, so not sure if I can avoid it.

Comment: `tasks.map { |t| inventory[[t[:position_id], t[:from]]].take_while { true } }` works for me like a charm.

Comment: As with many questions like this, I'd say your starting point is non-ideal. How did you get those big hashes? There seems to be a propensity to build up big data structures, only to throw them away once you've extracted what you need. The data structures themselves are not really used. This is inefficient. I say throw out the middleman and create the output you want directly from the source (e.g. ActiveRecord queries) instead of building up a big hash you must then parse.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thank you, I've cut out everything I could. It gave me some benefits, I even created some smart model associations :) At the end I see I have to do this iteration to get values I need. At the moment I've figured out the last obstacle - there might be `tasks` not matching `inventory` so I need to somehow skip `take_while` if there is `nil`.

Comment: If you're using ActiveRecord, you certainly have not cut out everything. Your results can come from an AR query directly, no tasks and inventory data structures needed.

Comment: @MarkThomas I'd really like to do the way you say, however I don't know how to do such advanced query. Would you take a look on my models    and queries I have if I put it somewhere, please?

Comment: I recommend you post a different question, asking how to get the result you want from an AR query. Tag it [tag:Ruby-on-Rails] and include your models, your desired result, and your attempt at producing it. You should get good feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra pair of square brackets is needed here:

```
inventory[[bt[:position_id], bt[:from]]]
```

Without the extra brackets the 2 values, `bt[:position_id]` and `bt[:from]`, are treated as 2 separate parameters to the hash lookup: `[]`.

Alternatively, you can clarify by using a temporary variable:

```
inventory_key = bt[:position_id], bt[:from]
inventory[inventory_key].take_while...
```

---

Note: you shouldn't be using `to_s` when building the key. If key in `inventory` is a `[Fixnum, DateTime]` then you need to look it up with same.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this already and this gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method "take_while" for nil:NilClass` error. What else can I try, please?

Comment: That suggests an entry in `tasks` that doesn't have a corresponding entry in `inventory` and so the hash lookup is returning `nil`.

Comment: It seems to be it is because `inventory_key = bt[:position_id], bt[:from]` produces `3 2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300` without comma. How do I tweak code to have `3, 2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300` with comma as end result, please?

Comment: Are you using `puts` to debug? That just sounds like the way `puts` will represent the array. Try using `p` or `.inspect` for better debug output. If you're still struggling then update the question with a *complete* example of the failing code so that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: I've added an extra note based on your updates to the question.

Comment: I thought `to_s` could help. I seen in console my `tasks` give me `:position_id=>3, :from=>2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300` and then in `inventory` I have `[3, 2017-09-04 18:00:00 +0300]` however when I do `tasks.map { |t| inventory[[t[:position_id], t[:from]]].take_while { true } }` I still get `undefined method "take_while" for nil:NilClass` error. Any ideas why so? When I do same thing in console with DateTime.new then it works.

Comment: I think I found my problem. It appears that there are `tasks` which do not match any `inventory` so it returns as `nil`. Basically I need to figure out, how to skip `take_while` when there is `nil` returned.